# Programmatic access to battery information in iOS12

Tags: ios, swift, battery, ios12

Apple recently created the new battery info and usage information in the Settings app. Is it possible to access this information programmatically to be used in my own app?

Comment: You should provide more information. Have you looked through any of the [iOS documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620045-isbatterymonitoringenabled) or [searched for this information anywhere](https://www.google.com/search?q=iOS+developer+documentation+battery+info&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS686US686&oq=iOS+developer+documentation+battery+info&aqs=chrome..69i57.2320j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no. UIDevice still has an `isBatteryMonitoringEnabled` toggle to turn on battery monitoring, which allows you to get values out of the `batteryLevel` and `batteryState` accessors and listen for the corresponding change notifications. You cannot, however, look at the proportion of battery consumed by other apps. See [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice?language=swift).